# Theoretical justification of Parametric bootstrap?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, bootstrap, nonparametric, consistency

I've been reading about bootstrap, and while it's relatively easy to find theoretical results (consistency and higher-order correctness) for the nonparametric bootstrap (e.g., Asymptotic Statistics by van der Vaart, 1998), I couldn't find any consistency or higher-order correctness results for the parametric bootstrap. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

After some thought, I realized that "consistency of parametric bootstrap" might be the wrong thing to ask for, because

- if the model was specified correctly, then as long as we use a consistent procedure such as MLE to estimate model parameters (so that the bootstrap sample is essentially generated from the "truth"), then of course the parametric bootstrap estimates is consistent;
- if the model was specified incorrectly, then there is no way that the bootstrap estimates will be consistent.

This might be wrong. I hope someone more experienced could check what I wrote.

Comment: van der Vaart's Lemma 23.3 handles parametric bootstrap consistency in your first case.   It's not quite as straightforward as you suggest: simulating from the MLE isn't the same as simulating from the truth and there are cases where the parametric bootstrap will fail

Comment: @ThomasLumley Thanks for getting back to me. (1) Yes van der Vaart's Lemma 23.3 is a general argument that would work for parametric bootstrap, but it seems to me that the lemma says "Assuming that the bootstrap estimator is consistent in the KS distance sense, then the bootstrap confidence interval is consistent." So the first sentence of the lemma is already assuming consistency (the two quantities both converge weakly to $T$).

Comment: (2) "simulating from the MLE isn't the same as simulating from the truth" Agreed. I was just re-reading van der Vaart theorem 23.4 and 23.5, and it looks like if we just replace the empirical distribution with that obtained from the parametric bootstrap, then the proof would go through without any problems. So we should be good for any statistics that are functions of the sample mean. But for more complicated statistics, whose consistency requires empirical processes, I don't think the proof (of theorem 23.7, 23.9) can be easily adapted.